# fancybox shows on one page (aaa.html) the forward buttons and on the other page not

Tags: jquery, fancybox

My name is Piet Hazewinkel and I made a website about a little village in France but I have a problem with Fancybox. I've made a testpage (www.francetastique.eu/aaa.html) with 2 pictures to show with fancybox. It works fine. I want that it works also on the page (www.francetastique.eu/fotofancy.html). But it does not works. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is there anybody who can help me? Thanks a lot for your help.
Piet

Comment: the reason you have js errors (and why fancybox is not working) is because you are loading two version of jQuery when you only need one instance (preferably the latest version) and loaded before of any plugin.

Comment: you are including 2 jquery file that should be causing a problem.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat : the OP is duplicating jQuery and you are duplicating my comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' (from Chrome debugger)

Maybe the error starts in
line 8: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the loading of two jQuery files. After deleting one, it runs now. Thanks JFK and rajesh for your answers.